# I don't understand the meaning of the particles "-off" and "-out"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I'm a French student and I don't understand the meaning of the particle "off" or "out" often used with verbs... Can anybody help me to understand their meaning?

For example "to phase out" or "live off"

Furthermore, I would like to ask you if this sentence is correct

> I neither understand the particle "off" nor "out".

Comment: Both prepositions have a range of meanings according to the exact context. For example, I might say (1) *He lives **out** his dreams* or (2) *He lives **off** his dreams*. The first means he *realises* (makes a reality of) his dreams, but the second (somewhat less likely utterance) would probably be taken to mean he *makes a living out of his dreams* (perhaps as a successful fantasy writer). There's usually an element of "meaning" associated with the preposition, but it's not always clear-cut - especially when we're considering the specific pair ***out*** and ***off***.

Comment: For example, a football manager deciding which players to field for an upcoming game could say *I think I'll **strike out** [PlayerX]* to mean *I've decided that PlayerX will **not** be in the team*. But he could have said *I think I'll **strike off** [PlayerX]*, with *exactly* the same meaning (remove from a list). Plus there's *striking out/off on a journey* (beginning, taking the first steps), which are again interchangeable. But in many other cases there may be a huge difference (or one preposition may simply never be used in that context). In summary, the question is probably Too Broad.

Comment: This question is much too broad. It cannot be approached like this. Perhaps it is useful at this point for you (the OP) to learn the term: phrasal verb.

Comment: Here is an introduction to phrasal verbs: https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2014/09/24/an-introduction-to-phrasal-verbs/ In order to get more information using google, the term /phrasal verb/ is needed.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand the meaning of the particle "off" or "out" often used with verbs

*Off* or *out* in some cases doesn't have a strong meaning in and of itself, but it exists to change the meaning of the main verb.  These are called *phrasal verbs*.

It usually is possible to use the words with their original meaning as well.

*Knock* is a verb that has phrasal variations with *out* and *off* as an example:

> To knock = To sharply and quickly tap something, e.g. with knuckles or a tool.  You can do this to disloge something or to make a sound against something like a door.
>
> To knock out = To lose consciousness, typically from a blow suffered
>   during a fight.  Can also mean to knock something in order to move it outward.
>
> To knock off = To stop doing something, parents typically tell their children this.  Can also mean to knock something in order to move it off of a surface.

Examples:

> I knocked the panel out of the cabinet = I sharply/quickly tapped the cabinet (with a hammer) to make it fall *out*.
>
> John knocked out Fred in the fight = Fred lost consciousness because John struck a blow to him in the fight.
>
> John knocked it out of the park (Common thing to say if John was playing baseball and struck a home run)
>
> That stupid cat knocked the figurines off the shelf.
>
> I told Sally to knock off the loud noise and she turned her stereo down.

Comment: Even if we limit ourselves to the specific "base" verb ***knock***, this is a far from complete list. There's *to knock **off** = to do something hastily, to kill, to steal, to have sex with,* etc. All I can say is *Knock yourself out* (which can mean *Enjoy yourself!* as well as *Apply yourself energetically (to the point of exhaustion).*

Comment: @LawranceC Last time I looked, a phrasal verb is a verb + a preposition. Who said anything about a complete list???

Comment: It's not a preposition when it's used as part of a verb. Just like other words change their function based on usage, the same applies here. "To bed" someone is different than "a bed" - one is a verb, the other a noun.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the best way to handle verb-preposition pairs is to treat each one as a separate verb, with its own meaning, usage, nuance, etc.  For example, the meaning of the verb "to get" changes greatly depending on which preposition is used with it:

> I get a banana (*obtain*)
>
> I get on the train (*embark*)
>
> I get off the train. (*disembark*)
>
> I get out of the house (*exit*)
>
> I get over a cold (*recover*)
>
> I get through the winter (*endure*)
>
> I get in a cab (*ride*)
>
> I get into my work (*focus*)

and various others.  "Off" and "out" are similar -- the meaning is not completely consistent between one verb and another.  For example:

> go off (*travel away*)
>
> leave off (*omit*, or *stop*)
>
> see out (*show to the exit*)
>
> go out (*go outside*, also *date* )
>
> leave out (*omit*, or *forget*)
>
> cookout (*a meal eaten outdoors*)

and so on.

Comment: At this point in the game for the OP, this is probably the best one can do. :)